# Как решить проблему с прогресс-баром?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Суть проблемы такова: есть страница, на которой прокручивается один из блоков. Необходимо "связать" прогресс-бар с этим блоком.

```js
$('.all').scroll(function() {
  var ratio = $('.all').scrollTop() / (($('.all').height() - $('.all').height()) / 100);
  $("#progress").width(ratio + "%");
});
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: Adineue;
  src: url("../fonts/adineue.ttf");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: ABold;
  src: url("../fonts/adineue-bold.ttf");
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Adineue';
  font-size: 20px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

header {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #141516;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  header {
    height: 5vh;
  }
}

header .header-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

header .logo {
  max-width: 75%;
  margin-left: 12.5%;
}

header .lang {
  margin-bottom: 5vh;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 60px;
}

.navbar-header {
  z-index: 3;
}

.navbar-header .toggle-button {
  height: 5vh;
  width: 5vw;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 5vh;
  z-index: 3;
}

.navbar-header .toggle-button:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
}

.bar {
  background-color: #fff;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 30px;
  height: 1px;
  border: 0;
  transition: all 0.35s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.055, 0.675, 0.19);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bar+.bar {
  margin-top: 4px;
}

.middle {
  top: 11px;
}

.bottom {
  top: 22px;
}

.toggle-active .bar {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.toggle-active .top {
  transform: translateY(0px) translateX(0) rotate(45deg);
}

.toggle-active .middle {
  opacity: 0;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
}

.toggle-active .bottom {
  transform: translateY(-10px) translateX(0) rotate(-45deg);
}

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  background: #575757;
  background: rgba(87, 87, 87, 0.56);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
  transition: opacity 0.35s, visibility 0.35s, height 0.35s;
}

.overlay .rofas-nav {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 3vh;
  left: 10vw;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 400;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.overlay .info-nav {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 30vh;
  left: 10vw;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 400;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.overlay ul li {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 1vh;
}

.overlay ul li a {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.overlay ul li a span {
  font-family: 'ABold';
  font-size: 1em;
}

.nav-active {
  opacity: 1;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
  visibility: visible;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 2;
}

.roof-link:hover {
  color: #e64e4e;
}

.fasad-link:hover {
  color: #f7a550;
}

.design-link:hover {
  color: #fedd32;
}

.industry-link:hover {
  color: #51b9f1;
}

.eco-link:hover {
  color: #70ca57;
}

.stone-link:hover {
  color: #956ccc;
}

.roof {
  color: #e64e4e;
}

.fasad {
  color: #f7a550;
}

.design {
  color: #fedd32;
}

.industry {
  color: #51b9f1;
}

.eco {
  color: #70ca57;
}

.stone {
  color: #956ccc;
}

.slider {
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url("http://mysolaris.xyz/images/roof-main.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.slider-content {
  height: 100vh;
  color: #fff;
}

.slider_content {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: 3vw;
  margin-right: 3vw;
}

.slider_content span {
  font-family: 'Adineue';
  font-size: 1em;
  margin-top: 5vh;
}

.slider-text {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: baseline;
  margin-top: 33vh;
  margin-right: 1vw;
}

.slider-text h1 {
  font-family: 'Adineue';
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.slider-text span {
  color: #e64e4e;
  font-family: 'ABold';
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.slider-text p {
  font-family: 'Lato';
  font-size: 0.75em;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.btn-roof {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin-top: 24vh;
}

.btn-roof:hover {
  transform: rotate(-360deg);
  transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.055, 0.675, 0.19);
}

.hr {
  color: #e64e4e;
  background-color: #e64e4e;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  margin-top: 6vh;
}

.object-container {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
}

.all {
  margin-top: 40vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 40vw;
  height: 420%;
}

.for-all {
  width: 36vw;
  height: 26.35vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  cursor: pointer;
  filter: opacity(0.5);
}

.for-all:hover {
  filter: opacity(1);
}

.sub {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  width: 36vw;
  height: 7.05vh;
  margin-bottom: 8vh;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  font-family: 'Adineue';
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.11);
}

.sub a {
  color: #fff;
}

.sub a p {
  color: #fff;
}

.first {
  background-image: url("http://mysolaris.xyz/images/ruukki.png");
}

.second {
  background-image: url("http://mysolaris.xyz/images/cheker.png");
}

.third {
  background-image: url("http://mysolaris.xyz/images/bitum.png");
}

.fourth {
  background-image: url("http://mysolaris.xyz/images/elems.png");
}

.fifth {
  background-image: url("http://mysolaris.xyz/images/falz.png");
}

.sixth {
  background-image: url("http://mysolaris.xyz/images/gidro.png");
}

.seventh {
  background-image: url("http://mysolaris.xyz/images/mansard.png");
}

.eigth {
  background-image: url("http://mysolaris.xyz/images/metalo.png");
}

.nineth {
  background-image: url("http://mysolaris.xyz/images/samorez.png");
}

.tenth {
  background-image: url("http://mysolaris.xyz/images/vodostok.png");
}

.right-side {
  width: 10vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: 5vh;
}

.btn {
  display: block;
  width: 33px;
  height: 33px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 33px;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.149);
}

#progress {
  margin-bottom: 5vh;
  background: #F00;
  width: 0%;
  height: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pure-g">
  <div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-sm-1 pure-u-md-11-12">
    <div class="slider pure-g">
      <div class="slider-content pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-2">
        <div class="slider_content">
          <span>01</span>
          <div class="slider-text">
            <h1>Rofas <span>Roof</span></h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis </p>
          </div>
          <a href="index.html" class="btn-roof"><i class="fa fa-undo fa-rotate-90" style="color:#e64e4e"></i></a>
          <div id="progress"></div>
          <div class="hr"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="slider-right pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-2">
        <div class="object-container">
          <div class="all">
            <div class="for-all first"></div>
            <div class="sub one">
              <a href="#">
                <p>Модульная металлочерепица Ruukki</p>
              </a>
              <a href="#"><img src="icons/arrow.png"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="for-all second"></div>
            <div class="sub two">
              <a href="#">
                <p>Rofas Cheker</p>
              </a>
              <a href="#"><img src="icons/arrow.png"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="for-all third"></div>
            <div class="sub three">
              <a href="#">
                <p>Битумная черепица</p>
              </a>
              <a href="#"><img src="icons/arrow.png"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="for-all fourth"></div>
            <div class="sub four">
              <a href="#">
                <p>Элементы безопасности кровли</p>
              </a>
              <a href="#"><img src="icons/arrow.png"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="for-all fifth"></div>
            <div class="sub five">
              <a href="#">
                <p>Фальцевая кровля</p>
              </a>
              <a href="#"><img src="icons/arrow.png"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="for-all sixth"></div>
            <div class="sub six">
              <a href="#">
                <p>Гидро- тепло-пароизоляция</p>
              </a>
              <a href="#"><img src="icons/arrow.png"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="for-all seventh"></div>
            <div class="sub seven">
              <a href="#">
                <p>Мансардные окна</p>
              </a>
              <a href="#"><img src="icons/arrow.png"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="for-all eigth"></div>
            <div class="sub eight">
              <a href="#">
                <p>Металлочерепица</p>
              </a>
              <a href="#"><img src="icons/arrow.png"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="for-all nineth"></div>
            <div class="sub nine">
              <a href="#">
                <p>Саморезы для крепления</p>
              </a>
              <a href="#"><img src="icons/arrow.png"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="for-all tenth"></div>
            <div class="sub ten">
              <a href="#">
                <p>Водосточные системы</p>
              </a>
              <a href="#"><img src="icons/arrow.png"></a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="right-side">
            <a href="index.html" class="btn"><img src="icons/return.png"></a>
            <a href="#" class="btn" style="margin-top: 10vh"><img src="icons/speaker.png"></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `$('.all').height() - $('.all').height()` - сколько будет?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решено:

```
$('.object-container').scroll(function() {
            var ratio = $('.object-container').scrollTop() / (($('.all').height() - $(window).height()) / 100);
            $(".hr").width(ratio + "%");
        });
```